# Override MailChimp stylesheet with second stylesheet

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

Goal: change background color of "Subscribe" button on MailChimp embedded sign-up form on company website page

Question: MailChimp gives the CSS hook "input.button" to style the Subscribe button. How do I use this CSS to override the styles already in place?

The page I would like to edit: http://www.sieralearn.com/subscribe/

Here is how the button is written in the HTML of the page:

```
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
```

As far as I can tell, I don't have access to the stylesheet used by MailChimp to generate the embed code (http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css). Here is how the styles appear in the MailChimp stylesheet:

```
#mc_embed_signup .button {clear:both; background-color: #aaa; border: 0 none; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; margin: 0 5px 10px 0; padding: 0 22px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;}
```

Thank you for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this on my [blog](http://www.mrgeek.me) one year ago and I was planning to write a tutorial, but I think this answer on SO will help people. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTwsL/) with the required HTML and CSS used to style the opt-in Mailchimp form.

The `input.button` can be styled completely as you wish, and here's the piece of code that changes the entire button, but you can wish to just change the background-color. If you want to have a look at a detailed form styling, refer to the fiddle attached as it has more niceties.

```
input.button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #bbdaf7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #bbdaf7;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #bbdaf7;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #79bbff), color-stop(1, #378de5));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#79bbff', endColorstr='#378de5');
    background-color:#79bbff;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #84bbf3;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:700;
    padding:7px 32px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #528ecc;
}
```

Might wish to change the `:hover` with this piece of CSS.

```
input[class=button]:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#378de5', endColorstr='#79bbff');
    background-color:#378de5
}
```

**The HTML markup.**

```
<div class="bu1">
     <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
 </div>
```

The final result.

[image]

Another option (not tested) is to do this in your custom style sheet or wherever:

```
#mc_embed_signup .button { background-color:lightcoral; }
```

The effect, as tested using Chrome Developer Tools is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. I copied the CSS code for the button and pasted it into my stylesheet. Updated HTML on the page to match the code provided. I'm still seeing the default gray Subscribe button. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong. Any idea what it might be? Thank you!

Comment: The color of the button has changed for me. It is showing blue. Try clearing your cache or switch the browser for a while. Don't trust me, see this. http://i.imgur.com/WWgA563.png. Therefore, the change is indeed working as we'd expect.

Comment: Switching browsers and clearing the cache both helped. I can now see your formatting for the button. However, when I change the background color of the CSS code you provided for the `input.button` selector, it reverts to the original gray. I assume it is being overridden by the `#mc_embed_signup .button` selector. I don't want a gradient; just a flat background color. Thank you for your expertise!

Comment: You can also put the code I provided for input.button into #mc_embed_signup .button selector and that should do it. Remember, if I helped you, do +1 and mark as green. By the way, I can see that it's gray again, so try to make changes to the #mc_embed_signup .button instead.

Comment: Will do. You absolutely helped A TON. I accepted your answer (marked it as green). Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation (min. 15) to up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I'm too new to simply comment, but can't you simply copy the content of their stylesheet (http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css) into a new stylesheet of your own, and reference your new one (in place of the old one) on your subscribe page? You can then change any of the design elements you wish without fouling up the ones you like.

Comment: Yes! It makes sense, to me at least, that this should work. I copied the MailChimp stylesheet into my site stylesheet.

Comment: That should work, but I'm still having trouble. Steps: 1) copied the MailChimp stylesheet into my stylesheet, 2) replaced .button background color, 3) added `!important`. Still not working. Code from my stylesheet: `#mc_embed_signup .button {clear:both; background-color: #3C638 !important; border: 0 none; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; margin: 0 5px 10px 0; padding: 0 22px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;}`

Comment: How are your stylesheets placed in the header?